# JK flipflop code in verilog using structural

Tags: verilog

i am writing an verilog program for jk flipflop in structural level
my program is as follows:

```
module jkstruct(j,k,clk,q,qbar);

input j,k,clk;

output reg q,qbar;

initial begin q=1'b1;qbar=1'b0; end

wire x,y,w,z;

assign w=q;

assign z=qbar;

nand n1(x,z,j,clk);

nand n2(y,k,w,clk);

nand n3(q,x,z);

nand n4(qbar,y,w);

endmodule
```

> ERROOR:Simulator:754 - Signal EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
>   receivedPrinting stacktrace...

was appearing on simulator error panel.
I am using xilinx 13.4 licensed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initialising outputs with

```
initial begin q=1'b1;qbar=1'b0; end
```

When they are combinatorially driven from :

```
nand n3(q,x,z);
nand n4(qbar,y,w);
```

The above requires the output to be connected via wire not reg.

Remove the initial, and reg declaration (apply change to below), and report back if the issue still persists.

```
output q,qbar; // was output reg q,qbar;
```

Comment: Actually i wants to make flipflop state as logic-1 so thats why i made  q=1'b1 &qbar=1'b0..

Comment: @Grouse you can not 'preset' the outputs from a different level of hierarchy like that. `n3` and `n4` are driving those values. If you want to change the output on a combinatorial block change the inputs. If you want to change initial state, swap `q` and `qbar`.